# Pumping Lemma to prove that L is not context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I have the language [image: L = {a^ib^jc^k : 0 \leq i \leq j \leq k}] and I want to prove that is not context-free.

So I started like this:
[image: p\in \mathbb{N}_{0}] is variable.
Choose w = [image: a^pb^pc^p]

*Case 1:*
vxy has no c. Choose i = 2
[image: uv^ixy^iz] has more a than c or more b than c.
[image: \Rightarrow uv^ixy^iz\notin L]

*Case 2:*
vxy has no a.

At case 2 I don't know how to continue, I'm confused since I seem to be not able to prove that there is a case where vxy has no a and the word's b-count or c-count is smaller than the amount of a's.

Comment: The pumping lemma also includes the case $i=0$ (where the $i$ is from the Lemma, not the $i$ from the definition of $L$).

Comment: What are you trying to say? You mean I shouldn't be shadowing those variables?

Comment: In Case 2 take $i=0$ in the pumping. That will delete $b$'s and or $c$'s while the $a$'s stay constant. What I added is that there is another $i$ in the definition of $L$. That can be confusing, but with some care you are OK.

Comment: Ah thanks. so those 2 cases are enough, right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to argue that, using the length condition on $vxy$.